# Why do inverse directions give correct movement?

Tags: ros, gazebo

I am currently working on driving a bot based on the location of a white ball and I find that giving it negative angular movement moves it to the left rather than the right. Here's a code snippet for what my instruction. Note that for left direction `drive_bot` has `0.0` linear direction in the `x-axis` but `0.5` instead of `-0.5` for angular motion. The entire project is [here](https://github.com/here2infinity/go_chase_it) but I provide my main code here.

```
void process_image_callback(const sensor_msgs::Image img)
{
  const int white_pixel = 255;
  const int image_slice_width = img.step / 3;

  int j;
  bool found = false;

  for (int i = 0; not found and i < img.height; i++)
  {
    for (j = 0; j < img.step; j++)
    {
      // img.data only has one index
      if (img.data[i*img.step +  j     ] == white_pixel and
          img.data[i*img.step + (j + 1)] == white_pixel and
          img.data[i*img.step + (j + 2)] == white_pixel)
      {
          found = true;
          break;
      }

    }
  }

void drive_bot(float linear_x, float angular_z)
{
  // Request a service and pass the velocities to it to drive the robot

  // ROS_INFO_STREAM("Driving bot");
  ball_chaser::DriveToTarget srv;
  srv.request.linear_x = linear_x;
  srv.request.angular_z = angular_z;

  if (not client.call(srv))
  {
    ROS_ERROR("Failed to call service drive to target");
  }

}

  if (found)
  {
    // determine which third of image ball is
    switch (j / image_slice_width) // split into 3
    {   
      case 0: // white ball to the left
        drive_bot(0.0, -0.5);
        ROS_INFO_STREAM("LEFT");
        break;
      case 1: // white ball in front
        drive_bot(0.5, 0.0);
        ROS_INFO_STREAM("FORWARD");
        break;
      default: // white ball to the right 
        drive_bot(0.0, 0.5);
        ROS_INFO_STREAM("RIGHT");
        break;
    }   
  }
  else
  {
    // no white pixel seen so stop the bot
    drive_bot(0.0, 0.0);

  }
```

I suspect that it may be how the model is put together but I don't see how those values show up in my `my_robot.xacro` and `my_robot.gazebo` [linked here](https://github.com/here2infinity/go_chase_it/tree/master/catkin_ws/src/my_robot/urdf).

Comment: note: calculate `i*img.step` before the second `for` loop ... you are calculating it needlessly numerous times inside the second loop ... you are also checking the same pixel three times in a row, first at `j+2`, then at `j+1` and again at `j` .... check only one pixel and check the next only if the first is white ... increment `j` by 3 if you find white/white/unwhite

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I made those changes but kept the signs and it still moves the same way - in the opposite direction.

Comment: i did not say that it would give you a different result ... it only made the code faster

Comment: i do not actually understand what problem you are having ... i see no problem with data being inverted ... all you have to do is multiply the result by -1